# multiple checkboxes for a model's column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I have in my company model:

```
 attr_accessible  :type
```

This model column type is a string and can have values Security, Event, Labour Provider, Union, Venue, Traffic Control, Construction, Hospitality, or Other.

So, in my view I need something like this ( []-> checkbox):

```
Company type:  
  [] Security  
  [] Event  
  [] Labour Provider  
  [] Union  
  [] Venue  
  [] Traffic Control  
  [] Construction  
  [] Hospitality  
  [] Other
```

User should be able to check one of the boxes when they create company, and that corresponding value should be saved in a company type.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can only contain one of Security, Event, Labour Provider, Union, Venue, Traffic Control, Construction, Hospitality, or Other, you probably want radio buttons, not check boxes.  You can use the `radio_button_tag` tag for that.

Try something like this:

```
<% [ 'security', 'event', 'labour_provider', 'union', 'venue', 'traffic_controller', 'construction', 'hospitality', 'other' ].each do |type| %>
  <br /><%= radio_button_tag :type, type %>
  <%= label_tag 'type_' + type, type.titleize %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

first, I think, you need more a radiobutton here, rather then checkbox: otherwise it would be possible for user to check several options.

Then, you should end up with something like this:

```
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="type">Type:</label>
    <% [ 'Security', 'Event', 'Labour', 'Provider', 'Union', 'Venue', 'Traffic Control', 'Construction', 'Hospitality', 'Other'].each do |type| %>
      <br><%= radio_button_tag 'type', type, @type == type %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```